# Laravel inserting "null" into database from form input.

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, null

This is a strange problem i've run into.  I have a form that takes in First, Last, Title, Email, and Phone which takes that data and inputs into a ContactPerson table I have set up in a database.

When I fill out the form, and hit submit, only the Title, Email, and Phone number get inserted correctly into the database. The first and last names get inserted as NULL.

Here's some of my code that I have using PHPstorm and Laravel 2.5.3

My Create a New Contact view:

```html
<h1 style="text-align:center;">Add A New Contact Person</h1>

    <hr/>

    {!! Form::open(['url' => '/create']) !!}

    <span style="text-align:center;align-content:right;display:block; margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;">

        <div class="form">
            {!! Form::label('first', 'First Name: ') !!}
            {!! Form::text('First', null, ['class' => 'form']) !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form">
            {!! Form::label('last', 'Last Name: ') !!}
            {!! Form::text('Last', null, ['class' => 'form']) !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form">
            {!! Form::label('title', 'Title: ') !!}
            {!! Form::text('Title', null, ['class' => 'form']) !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form">
            {!! Form::label('email', 'Email: ') !!}
            {!! Form::text('Email', null, ['class' => 'form']) !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form">
            {!! Form::label('phone', 'Phone: ') !!}
            {!! Form::text('Phone', null, ['class' => 'form']) !!}
        </div>

        {!! Form::submit('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary form']) !!}

    </span>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Here is my controller called ResourceController I have created:

```html
class ResourceController extends Controller
{
    public function resource()
    {
        $contacts = ContactPerson::all();

        return view('pages.resource', compact('contacts'));     
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('pages.create');
    }

    public function store(Requests\CreateNewContactRequest $request)
    {
        ContactPerson::create($request->all());

        return redirect('resource');
    }
}
```

Here's the validation I have set up in the CreateNewContactRequest class for the form:

```html
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'First' => 'required|min:2',
        'Last' => 'required|min:1',
        'Title' => 'required|min:2',
        'Email' => 'required|Email|unique:users',
        'Phone' => 'required|numeric|min:9'
    ];
}
```

Here's what it looks like when I fill out/submit the form.

[image: Creating new contact]

After hitting submit it redirects to the database dump:
[image: after submitting]

the view of the database after insertion:
[image: database]

Comment: check that the feild names match your schema also that the fillable variable has all those fields so they can add the to.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your dump details, your field names need to match your form names or visa versa, so your form names need to change to say:

```
   <div class="form">
        {!! Form::label('first', 'First Name: ') !!}
        {!! Form::text('First_Name', null, ['class' => 'form']) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form">
        {!! Form::label('last', 'Last Name: ') !!}
        {!! Form::text('Last_Name', null, ['class' => 'form']) !!}
    </div>
```

EG for field name `First_Name` your input needs to be named the same `name="First_Name"`

Also making sure your fillable details are also correct

```
 protected $fillable = ['First_Name','Last_Name','Title','Email','Phone'];
```